# Problem using php ODBC functions from within a Joomla article

Tags: php, windows, apache, joomla, odbc

I am new to Joomla and new to php (wish I was so new in age too). I have installed joomla on a local [apache webserver](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html). I am trying to use some php code in a joomla article in order to fetch some data from a Sybase ASE 12.5 database. I installed [sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/5051) and started to try an ODBC connection using a system DSN (which I verified it is working):

```
{source}
<?php
echo 'This text is placed through <b>PHP</b>!';
echo '<p>';
echo '</p>';

$conn = odbc_connect('myDSN', 'sa', 'myPassword') or die('Could not connect !');
echo 'Connected successfully';

$sql = 'SELECT day, name FROM my_table where month = 1';

odbc_close($conn);

?>
{/source}
```

The above code doesn't do much, but this is how far I can get without problems. I refresh the joomla page and I see inside the article's text:

```
...
This text is placed through PHP!

Connected successfully 
...
```

Seems ok, the connection obviously established (I verified this by stopping the sybase service and getting the "*Could not connect*" message). Then I added one more line, just below the $sql assignment.

```
$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
```

I refresh and ...I see nothing coming from the script (not even the *"This text is placed through PHP!"*).
Obviously, I see nothing if I include code to echo the contents of $rs. I also tried this but in vain.

```
if (!$rs)
{exit("Error in SQL");}
```

Once I add the `odbc_exec` command, the entire script ceases working.
In php.ini I read:

```
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
```

Do you have any idea what is going wrong?

- **UPDATE**

Connecting to a MySQL database using code [like this](http://php.tonnikala.org/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php), works like a charm.

Comment: A blank page is usually indicative of a fatal error, like a parse error. Turn on error reporting with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the script (alternatively, I think Joomla has a backend interface to turn on error reporting in the Global Configuration>Server Tab). If this is an error from the database you can use `odbc_error()`. Try `odbc_exec($conn,$sql) or die(odbc_error());` to see if any useful info is produced.

Comment: Iam not getting a blank page. I get the article's page as if there were no script included whatsoever!

Comment: @db047, is this code part of plug-in/component or a separate page included as a wrapper? Anyways, enabled error_reporting and see what is causing the problem...

Comment: This is the code that this plug in allows me to insert in the article's text. See this http://www.nonumber.nl/images/stories/extensions/sourcerer/screenshot_editor_button.png. Anyway, I tried the above but to no avail. I always see the rest of article's text without getting any errors, as if there's no php script at all.

Comment: In general the question is: Is this the correct way to get data from another database in to an article or should I use some plug-in to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question

> Is this the correct way to get data
>   from another database in to an article
>   or should I use some plug-in to do
>   that?

The correct way is to use `JDatabase` object which you get by `JFactory::getDBO()` or `JDatabase::getInstance()`, see [Joomla JDatabase documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/JDatabase).

```
$db = JDatabase::getInstance( $databasConfigArray );
$db->setQuery('your query');
$data = $db->loadObjectList();
```

[Here is a good tutorial showing how to connect to multiple databases in Joomla](http://www.boolcast.com/development/using-multiple-databases-within-joomla-framework), there is even source code for helper class.

Also look at this thread [Connecting to 3rd party databse in Joomla!?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597034/connecting-to-3rd-party-databse-in-joomla/3593550)